# random velocity vector formula

Tags: javascript, html, physics

I am creating a game where on start, the ball needs to go in a random direction on the html canvas, but all ways have the same velocity. This isn't what I need:

```
vx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
vy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
```

Because it will not give a constant velocity.
Could you please think up a formula?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want a constant speed with a random direction? Then use

```
phi = 2*Math.PI*Math.random();
vx = speed * Math.cos(phi);
vy = speed * Math.sin(phi);
```

Comment: For some reason, for me it won't always stay in a constant velocity

Comment: You would have to document what happens next to the velocity vector. (And possibly how you measure the scalar velocity.)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you work in Java and want a random vector with a magnitude of 20?

First, your vector isn't truly random to begin with. Math.random() yields a positive number between 0 and 1 so your vector always points toward the same quadrant of the coordinate system (with both coordinates positive). I think what you want is something like Math.random()*2 - 1 to create coordinates between -1 and 1.

Second, you need to normalize your vector: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalizedVector.html

Finally, multiply both vector coordinates by the magnitude you want your vector to have, in your case 20, probably.

Comment: Could you provide an example code, like in the answer above?